# Extern pointer initialization

Tags: c++

I have this class:

Logger.h

```
class Logger{

    std::string filename;
    std::ofstream fileStream;

    /*Some methods ...*/
};

extern Logger* log;
```

In another header file i have included the *log definition:

Foo.h

```
#include "Logger.h"

class Foo{
    Logger* log;

    /*Other code*/
};
```

But if in Foo.cpp file i try to do this:

```
log = new Logger();
```

the compiler give me an error, any idea?

Comment: For all questions, it *greatly* helps to state which error the compiler gives. Actually, it often even helps to find the mistake yourself if you meditate a few seconds about the error message.

Comment: Where in Foo.cpp? Why not putting the relevant code for us to see and the compiler error?

Comment: There's also some ambiguity between Foo::log and the global log in Logger.h... Where is `log = new Logger()` being called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, variables *declared* as `external` must be defined. So you need to have

```
Logger *log;
```

in `Logger.cpp`. You can also initialize it there like this:

```
Logger *log = new Logger();
```

Second, you don't need any more declarations, that is you just need to include `Logger.h`, no need to declare another `Logger` variable in `Foo.h`, just use `log` from `Logger.h`.

Comment: Thanks! It works, is my first time with extern pointer ... thanks again!

Comment: One question, this variable is a pointer, why i can't allocate it in another class at runtime?

Comment: You should be able to allocate it anywhere. Just make sure you don't allocate it several times without deleting previous allocations.

Comment: Oh, and you should make sure you allocate it before using it.